# New user input for which variable in a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm making a program that takes numbers as an input and than compares them with each other to find the lowest one. Since I don't want to do it

```
printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &a);
```

three times since it takes time I thought to do it with a for loop.I made one tho, I know its not perfect since it doesn't do what I'm actually looking for.

What I expect is that the loop go through print the printf statement, takes " a " as a user input, print again the statement and now takes " b " variable as a user input and after completing the loop it will go to the conditionals.

Many Thanks in advance :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void min(){
    int a, b, c;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    }
    if (a < b && a < c){
        printf("This number: %d is the lowest one.\n", a);
    }
    else if (b < a && b < c){
        printf("This number: %d is the lowest one.\n", b);
    }
    else if (c < a && c < b){
        printf("This number: %d is the lowest one.\n", c);
    }
    else{
        printf("Error. You might have entered a floating point number or a character. Please check again\n");
     }
}

int main() {

     min();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Each time around the loop, you're reading in 3 numbers which is definitely not want you want. Might be a good time to read about arrays in the book you're learning C from.

Comment: You need to indent your code.

Comment: You can save the user typed number in each round of a loop, in an array of ints, or in different variables, but it takes the same time that doing three times the printf-scanf process. The time is spended waiting for the user 3 times. You don't earn anything doing it in a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to initialize 3 variables. You can use a temporary variable and assign it to the array index.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void min(){
    int arr[3], temp;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
            printf("Enter a number: ");
            scanf("%d", &temp);
            arr[i]=temp;
    }

    if (arr[0] < arr[1] && arr[0] < arr[2]){
            printf("This number: %d is the lowest one.\n", arr[0]);
    }
    else if (arr[1] < arr[0] && arr[1] < arr[2]){
            printf("This number: %d is the lowest one.\n", arr[1]);
    }
    else if (arr[2] < arr[0] && arr[2] < arr[1]){
            printf("This number: %d is the lowest one.\n", arr[2]);
    }
    else{
            printf("Error. You might have entered a floating point number or a character. Please check again\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    min();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments above, you read 3 variables in one iteration, thus reading 9 times. Also, you can't write a reasonable elegant code to read `a`, `b` and `c` in a loop, as you would need to make if's or switches to determine what variable to read taking the index `i` into account.

It would be better to use an int array instead:

```c
    int a[3];
```

Then you would read inside your loop:

```c
    for (int i = 0; i < 3, i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
```

also, note that you would need to iterate from [0..2]!

Then use `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]` instead of `a`, `b` and `c`.